# Derived class doesn't recognise arguments of method from parent

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to make a set of functions to operate easily through some data. 
The problem I'm facing is: it seems to recognize and use methods from the parent class, except one: `show()`, giving me errors about **unexpected arguments**.

Here's a sample of the classes:

```
from treelib import Tree, Node

class Join(Tree):

    def __init__(self, id, desc, childs=(), *args, **kwargs):

        Tree.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.id = id
        self.desc = desc
        self.value = None
        self.parent = None
        self.childs = None

        self.create_node(tag=desc, identifier=id)

        for i in childs:
            self.paste(self.id, i)

    def getSons(self):
        sons = self.children(self.id)
        return sons

    def getID(self):
        return self.id

    def getDesc(self):
        return self.desc

    def show(self):
        self.show(key=lambda x: x.tag, reverse=True, line_type='ascii-em')

class Get(Tree):

    def __init__(self, id, desc, primitive, *args, **kwargs):

        Tree.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.id = id
        self.desc = desc
        self.parent = None
        self.primitive = primitive

        self.create_node(tag=desc, identifier=id, data=primitive)

    def getID(self):
        return self.id

    def getDesc(self):
        return self.desc

    def show(self):
        self.show(key=lambda x: x.tag, reverse=True, line_type='ascii-em')

class Primitive():

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    def show(self):
        pass
        #print '\t -> ' + str(self.value)
```

If, for example, I do this on another .py

```
prim = Primitive(0)
get1 = Get("get1", "Some random thing", prim)
get1.show()
```

it tells me that `key` is an unexpected argument. I even checked the library's .py file, the argument is there:

```
def show(self, nid=None, level=ROOT, idhidden=True, filter=None,
         key=None, reverse=False, line_type='ascii-ex'):
```

The `create_node()` method works just fine! That's what's weird. Any suggestions?

I'm using `treelib` in **Python 2.7**

Comment: `Tree.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` should be `super(Join, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Tried that earlier, same results. With and without 'self'...

Comment: Also, the super call should be after all the logic (last line of the init method)

Comment: But like that create_node will stop working. I no longer have _nodes attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `show()` calls itself:

```
def show(self):
    self.show(key=lambda x: x.tag, reverse=True, line_type='ascii-em')
```

Removed it in `Get` and change it in `Join` to:

```
def show(self):
    super(Join, self).show(key=lambda x: x.tag, reverse=True, line_type='ascii-em')
```

Comment: I never thought it would conflict the names of the methods since they were from distinct .py files. Just changing the name to **def showPrint(self):** did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Tree`'s source isn't part of this code. Did you mean change it in `Join.show`? If that's the case, the `super` should be `super(Join, self)`, not `super(Tree, self)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, thanks for the hint. Fixed. Mixed it up while scrolling up and down the long code.